# Move image in function

Tags: php

[image]

I have the following code below  i need to move an image so the rest of my data
displaying in pdf does not overlap the logo itself

```
function do_print(&$focus) {

    $this->set_focus($focus);
    $this->filename = $this->create_filename();
    $this->new_page();
    $this->print_logo();  //logo print details -- need to move this so rest dont overlap it.
    if(method_exists($this->layout, 'printCompanyAddress'))
        $this->layout->printCompanyAddress($this);
    $this->print_details();
    $this->print_extra_head();
    if($this->layout_name == 'QuotePDF')
        $this->print_addresses();
    else
        $this->layout->print_addresses($this);
    $this->print_main();
    //$this->print_notes();
    $this->print_terms();
    $this->print_extra_foot();
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged JavaScript? Am I missing something?

Comment: And what does print_logo() look like? You're question is like I like to move my bed to the left side. Here's a picture of my kitchen :-)

Comment: This question lacks so many info that it is impossbile to answer.

Comment: I've removed the `javascript` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the print_details() function. You will find an y offset there. Just increase the offset and the text will be pushed down the page

Comment: Is there a way that I can get the Date for the current moment to be displayed in there i am not that good with code yet so the help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sure, have a look at the print functions. Start by printing any text on the pdf, then switch to the date and adjust the positioning. Without more code there's no way we can help you with it